# yarn workspace triggers errors in a different package

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, nestjs, yarn-workspaces

I am trying to setup yarn workspace in an existing project. When running `yarn workspace @project/telemetry start:dev` TS errors are triggered in a completely different project `@project/web`.

> error TS2686: 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.

My project structure is the following:

```
project
  /node_modules
  /packages
    /common
    /web
    /telemetry
  tsconfig.json
  yarn.lock
```

I was able to run `yarn workspace @project/web dev` (Next.js) application after some tweaking with tsconfig and resolution. I was able to share a common lib to it as well.

The next step is to share the same common lib with telemetry (nest.js) service, but when running the service TS errors are triggered for /web somehow even though /telemetry never uses anything from /web.

project/package.json

```
{
  "name": "@project/root",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react": "17.0.38"
  }
}
```

project/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "types.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

project/packages/web/package.json

```
{
  "name": "@project/web",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "env-cmd -f environments/.env.development next dev",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@project/common": "*", // Shared common
    "micro": "^9.3.4",
    "next": "12.2.0",
    "next-connect": "^0.11.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.11",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "17.0.8",
    "@types/react": "17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.20.0",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.7",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.5.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "lint-staged": "^12.1.7",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^9.1.0",
    "tsc-files": "^1.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.5.4"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "tsc-files --noEmit --pretty"
    ],
    "*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}": [
      "eslint --cache --fix"
    ]
  }
}
```

project/packages/web/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.css"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "typeRoots": [
    "./global.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/@types"
  ]
}
```

project/packages/telemetry/package.json

```
{
  "name": "@project/telemetry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@project/common": "*", // Shared common
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.2.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "cache-manager": "^4.0.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "28.1.3",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.8",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

project/packages/telemetry/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```